# How can I display extra information when a selection is made?

Tags: php, html, css

For practice, on an html page, I have 2 buttons.

1 button was made using the  tag, and it redirects to another page. (this works)

The second button, when pressed needs to display more features and options that populate the blank area of the page.

Comment: You can create a form and post to the same page so that content is shown after reloading. If you want to display content without reloading the page, you are going to have to get into javascript.

Comment: Oh shoot.. I see, I am currently concentrating on only php and html. But that seems like a good solution
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

  $action = (isset($_GET['sent'])) ? $_GET['sent'] : null;
  If($action!=null){
   ?>
   Other buttons go here, <b>Hello</b>
<?php
  }

?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?sent=yes'; ?>" method="get">
   <input type="submit" value="Show more buttons" />
</form>
```

Give or take that should do what you want to do. Although I recommend learning as this method is a little annoying as the entire contents of the page have to be refreshed. When dealing with text, it's not so bad, but most websites have images.

Answer (score 1):

Try using CSS with javascript. Have the additional content in a separate     `div` that is     `position:absolute` and     `visibility:hidden`. Attach javascript to the 2nd button, so that click changes visibility to     `visible`.